# How can i parse below xml by php?

Tags: php, web-services, web

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:WS_CTM_People_ICEVA">
         <ns0:getListValues>
            <ns0:Person_ID>PPL000000301739</ns0:Person_ID>
            <ns0:Submitter>soehler</ns0:Submitter>
            <ns0:Profile_Status>Enabled</ns0:Profile_Status>
            <ns0:Locale2>en_US</ns0:Locale2>
            <ns0:VIP>No</ns0:VIP>
            <ns0:Client_Sensitivity>Standard</ns0:Client_Sensitivity>
         </ns0:getListValues>
      </ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: with code? What have you tried? There are almost certainly XML-parsing functions already available for PHP if you google it.

Comment: **FYI:** [bellow](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bellow&oq=bellow&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.175j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) vs [below](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=below&oq=below&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4280j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Secondly, what have you tried in terms of PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Simple HTML Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class. for example:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:WS_CTM_People_ICEVA">
         <ns0:getListValues>
            <ns0:Person_ID>PPL000000301739</ns0:Person_ID>
            <ns0:Submitter>soehler</ns0:Submitter>
            <ns0:Profile_Status>Enabled</ns0:Profile_Status>
            <ns0:Locale2>en_US</ns0:Locale2>
            <ns0:VIP>No</ns0:VIP>
            <ns0:Client_Sensitivity>Standard</ns0:Client_Sensitivity>
         </ns0:getListValues>
      </ns0:GetListBy_QualificationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$xml = str_get_html($xml);
print_r( $xml );
```

Read class documents and extract data from `$xml` variable.